# How can I find out if two arguments are instances of the same, but unknown class?

Tags: java, reflection, types, compare

Let us say we have a method which accepts two arguments o1 and o2 of type Object and returns a boolean value. I want this method to return true only when the arguments are instances of the same class, e.g.:

```
foo(new Integer(4),new Integer(5));
```

Should return true, however:

```
foo(new SomeClass(), new SubtypeSomeClass());
```

should return false and also:

```
foo(new Integer(3),"zoo");
```

should return false.

I believe one way is to compare the fully qualified class names:

```
public boolean foo(Object o1, Object o2){
 Class<? extends Object> c1 = o1.getClass();
 Class<? extends Object> c2 = o2.getClass();
 if(c1.getName().equals(c2.getName()){ return true;}
 return false;  
}
```

An alternative conditional statement would be :

```
if (c1.isAssignableFrom(c2) && c2.isAssignableFrom(c1)){ return true; }
```

The latter alternative is rather slow. Are there other alternatives to this problem?

Answer (score 10):

Don't bother with the fully qualified class names - just compare class references:

```
public boolean foo(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1.getClass() == o2.getClass();
}
```

Classes are essentially unique by name and classloader - so this will return false if the objects are of the same class *name* but loaded by different classloaders, but that's probably appropriate: they could be completely different classes in all but name! If the classes have the same name and classloader, however, they'll have the same reference.

Note that this will throw a `NullPointerException` if either `o1` or `o2` is null, but again that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you qualify rather slow?  Compared to what?  Also please elaborate your usage scenario?  In java the Object api includes a equals/hashCode method paring that should be used to identify equality between objects.  It appears as if this is what you may be attempting to find, ie:

```
new Integer(4).equals(new Integer(5))
```

In this case, the best implementation for overriding equals in SomeClass is as follows:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof SomeClass) {
        return ((SomeClass) obj).identityField.equals(identityField);
    }
    return false;
}
public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * identity.hashCode();
}
```

Making sure you provide an identity within your object.